# Create new user with Django Rest Framework JSON Web Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using Django REST framework, with Simple JWT. I am trying to create a user registration page. Currently, I am getting this error

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> Reason given for failure:
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Full error message here:[image: Error message]

Under settings.py, I have added this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),
```

}

My project urls folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("my_api.urls")),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/token', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('api/token/refresh', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
]
```

And this is my app's view for my registration endpoint.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "my_api/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            # Creates a hashed password. 
            #password = make_password(password)
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=email, email=email, password=password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(e)
            return render(request, "my_api/register.html", {
                "message": "Email address already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse("Successfully created account.")
    else:
        return render(request, "my_api/register.html")
```

Comment: Did you add the token to your html form? `{% csrf_token %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/

Comment: Ok that seems to have solved it... Closing this for now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is causing the error in case of me is that I tried to get the user with `http://localhost:8000/jwt/create` while my endpoints started with `auth/` so it should be `http://localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create` or in your case it should be

```
http://localhost:8000api/token/jwt/create
```

I wrote it thinking that some other user might have the same issue.